# UI Automation - Elements on my UI have ember ids , which change frequently with addition of new UI elements. How to use the id for automation?

Tags: selenium, ember.js, ui-automation

Example of the HTML of a dropdown element:

```
    <div aria-owns="ember-basic-dropdown-content-ember1234" tabindex="0" data-ebd-id="ember1234-trigger" role="button" id="ember1235" class="ember-power-select-trigger ember-basic-dropdown-trigger ember-view">  <!---->
    <span class="ember-power-select-status-icon"></span>
    </div>
```

The xpath and CSS selector also contain the same ember id.
xpath : //*[@id="ember1235"]
css selector : #ember1235

The ember id would change from id="ember1235" to say, id="ember1265" when there is a change in the UI.

I am using id to locate the element. But every time it changes I need to modify the code. Is there any other attribute I could use for Ember JS UI elements?

Comment: If you are looking for locating things uniquely, Community's recommended way to target elements within the test environment is [Ember Test Selectors](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-test-selectors). It uses [data] attributes and will be removed automatically in the Production build. I personally use it whenever I work with Ember's default test suite.

Comment: Implementing ember test selectors in the template needs to be done by the developer while designing/updating the UI elements?

Comment: Yeah. Right. The developer has to add those test selectors.

Comment: I work with a framework built on top of selenium. Would ember test selectors be compatible ? Is using ember test selector similar to using any other div attribute(like id) in ui automation scripts to locate ui elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is quite a lot to discuss in your question but hopefully we will have a good answer for you @PriyaK

The first thing to mention is that Ember IDs may not be the best method to select an element in the DOM. As you have already mentioned, they can change from time to time and also it doesn't really give you a great semantic thing to select in your selenium test so it might seem a bit out of context when looking back.

One thing that you could try is to either pass a class to the [ember-power-select](https://ember-power-select.com/) component (the one that provides the HTML that you used in your example) and use that to select the element, something like:

```html
<PowerSelect
  @class="my-fancy-class"
  as |name|
>
  {{name}}
</PowerSelect>
```

Then you should be able to select the selected value by using the CSS selector `.my-fancy-class span` (because the component outputs the selected value in a span)

We just tried this in an example app but it didn't actually work  Never fear, you can also do something like this and it should work with the same selector as before:

```html
<div class="my-fancy-class">
  <PowerSelect as |name|>
    {{name}}
  </PowerSelect>
</div>
```

This is fine, but there are also a few issues using classes for selectors in tests. One example of a problem that might crop up is that your tests might all suddenly stop working if you did a style refactor and changed or removed some of the classes on your elements. One technique that has become popular in the Ember community is to use `data-test-` attributes on your DOM nodes like this:

```
<div data-test-my-fancy-select>
  <PowerSelect
    @class="my-fancy-class"
    as |name|
  >
    {{name}}
  </PowerSelect>
</div>
```

which can then be accessed by the following selector: `[data-test-my-fancy-select] span`. This is great for a few reasons! Firstly it separates the implementation of your application and tests from your styling and avoids the issue I described above. The second benefit of this method is that using what @Gokul suggested in the comments, the [ember-test-selectors](https://github.com/simplabs/ember-test-selectors) package, you can make use of these `data-test-` selectors in your development and test environments but they will be **automatically removed from your production build**. This is great to keep your DOM clean in production but also, depending on the size of your application, could save you a reasonable amount of size in your templates on aggregate.

I know you say that you are using selenium for your testing but it's also worth mentioning that if you're using the [built-in Ember testing system](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/testing/) you will be able to make use of some testing helpers that addons may provide you. ember-power-select is one of those addons that provides specific testing helpers and you can read more about it in their documentation: https://ember-power-select.com/docs/test-helpers

I hope this answers any questions you had!

---

This question was answered as part of "May I Ask a Question" Season 3 Episode 1. If you would like to see us discuss this answer in full you can check out the video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1DAJXUucnQU

Comment: Thank you so much for the response and the video. I am considering to use ember test selectors to add unique test selectors to the element. Will get back if I have any more questions and also with the info on the ember version that we are using for our application.I just want to add that I am not an Ember developer. I am a QA and I want to build some automated regression tests for my web application that is developed using Ember JS. I chose a selenium based framework to write my tests.

Comment: It's ok that you're not an Ember developer, and if you would prefer to use selenium for your tests there is nothing in Ember that is preventing you from doing so. Essentially the essence of my answer is that you can't target the IDs as they are likely to change in Ember so you need to provide some other way to target elements from selenium.

Comment: Do you think this has answered your question then? if so can you set it as the accepted answer?